# How to calculate SHA256 hash IssuerKeyHash and IssuerNameHash From DER or PEM certificates

Tags: c, openssl, x509

I need to see these results with python openssl or c from x509 certificates to get a standard result.

Comment: If your question is about openssl C code... where is it? That code should be part of your question.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry I edited

Comment: which is your reference code, the C or the Java one?

Comment: @WalterTross Java result  for issuerKeyHash 3e1518dc6e867ea55d699922be7be6898fb5abf459709c086e17ac4760682da9 and C result 89EA6977E786FCBAEB4F04E4CCDBFAA6A6088E8BA8F7404033AC1B3A62BC36A1 
I need to fix that in code c

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what that Java code does. It simply takes the toString output from the public key of the cert, then slams it through a digest algorithm.  Ex: A 1024 RSA cert  in the java code, the pubkey toString method may return a string of the form `Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits <cr>params: null <cr> modulus: big long number` etc. The java code just takes that *string* and hashes it. You *really* just want C code that (a) generates a similar string, then (b) digests that? Besides brittle as all get out, that's somewhat suspect of sanity.

Comment: @WhozCraig I need to see these results with python openssl or c from x509 certificates to get a standard result. I appreciate your taking the time to answer my question(s).

Comment: Yeah, but .. if you want consistent results, you need to hash consistent data. If Java code is obtaining a hash by digesting a dependent representation (that could basically be anything), then the C code would have to do the same. I think what you need is a hash of the actual public key DER itself. I.e. open the cert, extract the public key DER, then sha-256 hash that. Done on *all* platforms with *all* toolsets, that should resolve the same result (assuming the comparison finality is also common. ex: you make a base64 encoding of the resulting hash in each case and compare the strings).